# The download files has the same name, but different hashsum

Tags: hashsum, testdisk

I downloaded "testdisk-7.2-WIP.linux-x86_64.tar.bz2" from 2020 and 2021, they have the name and seems same version, but have different hashsums. Looking inside the packages, one is created in 2019, another in 2021, how can I tell these two testdisk packages are real?

Comment: You check if a package is real by comparing its checksum with the checksum from the publisher. Files can also be digitally signed to confirm that they come from a legitimate source.

Comment: If the maintainer made slight modification with the 2021 upload then it can change the hashsum. That's is, if there was no error while downloading the package, check sum are only to check for data integrity. To check for data authenticity, we normally use a public key authentication mechanism called the pgp . And the most common implementation of that is the gpg tool by GNU. The maintainer need provide the digital signature for the package along with it. Which you will need to download along with the package, then you import the maintainers public and then verify.

Comment: So where to find the hashsums for each time of  `testdisk`

Comment: Normally there is a separate checksum file to download but you can also list the contents of the archive with `tar -jtvf` and see if there is anything listed such as a `README.txt` or something similar.

Comment: README.txt is extracted then open, but no checksum in it.

Comment: anyone can tell me?